# How to produce a line space in arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter, associative-array

```
$arr = array(
   'toemail'=>$v->agent_primary_email,
   'agentname'=>$v->agent_firstname,
   'agentid'=>$v->agent_id,
   'subject'=>'The details of total number of properties saved by your clients',
   'totalprop'=>$v->prop_count
);
echo json_encode($arr);exit;
```

The output looks like this

```
{"toemail":"abc@gmail.com","agentname":"john","agentid":"110012","subject":"The    details of total number of properties saved by your clients","totalprop":"131"}
```

But what changes should i have make, so that the output looks like this

```
{"toemail":"abc@gmail.com",
 "agentname":"john",
 "agentid":"110012",
 "subject":"The details of total number of properties saved by your                     clients",
 "totalprop":"131"}
```

Comment: i mean i want the output with a new line in each object,not everything in one line.

Comment: if its just for output styling purposes, just use `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` flag. its already in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) and also need to use `echo "<pre>"`;

[**From PHP Manual:**](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) Use whitespace in returned data to format it. Available since **PHP 5.4.0**

```
$array = array(
    'test'=>1,
    'test2'=>'test',
    'test3'=>'test 3'
);
echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode($array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**Result:**

```
{
    "test": 1,
    "test2": "test",
    "test3": "test 3"
}
```